# How to compare trunc value to avg value in oracle

Tags: oracle, plsql, average

I'm supposed to compare a truncated value with an average value. In my table I have 2 dates, order_date & ship_date; I use trunc(ship_date - order_date) to get the number of days it takes for item to be shipped. Now I want to compare the average of such time with the value I get from the `trunc()` function and if `trunc()` function is greater then I just wanna show the results.

This is what I have come up with so far, any help is appreciated.

```
select order_id, 
    order_date, 
    trunc(ship_date-order_date) as shipping_time 
from product_order 
where (trunc(ship_date-order_date) > Avg(trunc(ship_date-order_date)));
```

When I do this I get this error:

> ORA-00934: group function is not allowed here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a basic problem. It's not a `trunc` problem but is a classic "compare a value with the `average` value over entire table(or a subset)".

A classic approach would be to get the avg in a separate query that returns a scalar:

```
select 
   order_id, 
   order_date, 
   trunc(ship_date-order_date) as shipping_time 
from product_order 
where 
  trunc(ship_date-order_date) > (select avg(trunc(ship_date-order_date)) 
                                 from product_order);
```

Another approach would be(using an analytical function):

```
select * 
from(
    select 
       order_id, 
       order_date, 
       trunc(ship_date-order_date) as shipping_time 
       avg(trunc(ship_date-order_date)) over() as avgshipping
    from product_order 
    )
where shipping_date > avgshipping;
```